# Copy docx from template and use it as new

Tags: c#, templates, copy, new-operator, openxml-sdk

I'm using a "template.docx" to copy to my "newDoc.docx" to use some predefined styles or illustrations. 
But with this new content, i want to update fields and my table of contents, so it's easy to do it with a vba script, the user don't have to do anything.

But i have a problem, i juste want one execution at the first openning. But if i use the document_new method, my docx is not know as new.

So, how can i "set" it as a new file/doc when i copy it ? 
Or maybe i must use a vba variable, modify it when update to prevent for the others updates ?

Thx all !

Comment: I guess I'm confused here - are you looking to do this in VBA, VBScript or the Open XML SDK/C#? Can you post your code and then we can comment?

Answer (score 0):

I generate the doc based on a docx with c# using open xml sdk.

```
Dim oStory As Range
Dim oField As Field
For Each oStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    For Each oField In oStory.Fields
     oField.Update
    Next oField
Next oStory
```

but i wish to execute just one time for the first open.